# Qual a diferença entre os 2 select?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Segue o código:

Exemplo:

```
        using (var ctx = new dbEntities())
        {
            var resultado = ctx.Table.SqlQuery("Select * from Table WHERE id = 0 ").ToList<Table>();                
        }
```

Outro Exemplo:

```
private dbEntities db = new dbEntities();

        var query = from m in db.Table
                    where m.Id == 1
                    select m;
```

Qual das 2 é mais recomendado para fazer comando select ou update ou insert ou delete ?

Comment: Quando possível, sempre prefira utilizar a sintaxe da linguagem ou do framework para consultas, em vez de SQL puro. Pois haverá risco muito menor de problemas com SQL injection. Também poderá facilitar a portabilidade do sistema com relação a SGBD.

Comment: O asp.net mvc 5 tem várias forma de fazer comando select. Isso me confunda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matheus, a sua duvida não é necessariamente sobre `ASP.NET MVC`, mas sobre `Entity Framework` mas poderia ser aplicada a qual quer `ORM`.

**LINQ**

Eu diria que na maior parte do tempo, você deve optar pelo `LINQ`, seja `query syntax` ou `method syntax`, isto torna o eu código mais limpo, facilita a manutenção, etc.

**LINQ - Query Syntax**

```
using (var db = new dbEntities())
{
    var query = 
        from m in db.Table
        where m.Id == 1
        select m;
}
```

**LINQ - Method Syntax**

```
using (var db = new dbEntities())
{
    var query = db.Table.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => x);
}
```

No caso do `method syntax`, o `.Select(x => x)` é dispensável, está ai apenas para fins de demostração.

Quer saber a diferença entre os dois? nenhuma, o `query syntax` será transformado em `method syntax`, veja ele como um `syntactic sugar`, assim como o `foreach`.

**Entity SQL**

Porém caso queira ter um pouco mais de controle, ter a possibilidade de escrever a sua própria consulta e que a mesma funcione em qual quer `SGBD`, poderá optar pelo `Entity SQL`.

```
using (var db = new dbEntities())
{
    var esqlQuery = @"SELECT VALUE Entity FROM dbEntities.Table as Entity where Entity.Id = 1";
    var query = new ObjectQuery<Contact>(esqlQuery, db, MergeOption.NoTracking);
}
```

Não sei quanto as versões mais atuais do `EF`, mas em versões mais antigas, a `ExpressionTree` gerada pelo `IQueryable<T>` era primeiro traduzida para `Entity SQL`, para então ser convertida para o SQL Final.

Neste caso você estaria pulando uma etapa no processo, mas particularmente, não vejo um saldo positivo ao se trocar o `LINQ` por `Entity SQL`.

**SQL**

Deixe esta opção apenas caso necessite de um ajuste fino no SQL, seja por que a consulta é muito complexa, o ORM não está entregando um resultado satisfatório, etc.

```
using (var ctx = new dbEntities())
{
    var resultado = ctx.Table.SqlQuery("Select * from Table WHERE id = 1").ToList<Table>();                
}
```

Porém tenha em mente que utilizar `SQL Puro` dentro de um `ORM` irá matar boa parte das vantagens e recursos do mesmo, por exemplo, um `SQL` escrito para `SQL Server` pode vir a não funcionar para `PosgreSQL`, enquanto que o `LINQ` e o `Entity SQL` não irão enfrentar este tipo de problema.

**Conclusão**

Dê preferencia ao `LINQ`, apesar do potencial do `Entity SQL`, não vejo muito espaço para o mesmo nos dias atuais e reserve o `SQL`, seja `ANSI SQL`, `TSQL` ou `PL/SQL` para ocasiões especiais.

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou muito, obrigado